# Flatten image background using OpenCV/Numpy

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

I am creating an image analysis tool (using Python).
I already have segmented images resulting from Otsu thresholding.
Using the OpenCv kmeans function I reduced the amount of colors in my image to 4. 
One of the K-means clusters is supposed to be black background (BGR values [0,0,0] ).

Due to the algorithm of K-means, background pixels are now not [0,0,0] but show pixel values of e.g. [0,2,1].

I want this background cluster to absolute black again. An image is represented as 3D numpy array. Currently I am just iteratively adjusting the background:

```
    X, Y, Z = img.shape
    for xi in xrange(X):
        for yi in xrange(Y):
            if all([value < 10 for value in img[xi][yi]]): 
                img[xi][yi] = np.zeros((1,3), dtype=int)
```

This is a relatively slow operation. Are there smarter ways to to this, possibly using specialized OpenCV/Numpy functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could vectorize this operation like this:

```
In [29]: A = np.random.random_integers(0,10,(2,4,3))

In [30]: A
Out[30]: 
array([[[ 5,  9,  1],
        [ 4,  0,  2],
        [ 0,  5,  9],
        [ 8,  7,  8]],

       [[ 1,  6,  7],
        [ 8, 10,  9],
        [ 2, 10,  1],
        [ 9,  2,  3]]])

In [32]: np.all(A < 5, axis=-1)  # I chose a threshold of 5
Out[32]: 
array([[False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [33]: A[np.all(A < 5, axis=-1)] = 100  # and set the values to 100 to easily show what has changed

In [34]: A
Out[34]: 
array([[[  5,   9,   1],
        [100, 100, 100],
        [  0,   5,   9],
        [  8,   7,   8]],

       [[  1,   6,   7],
        [  8,  10,   9],
        [  2,  10,   1],
        [  9,   2,   3]]])
```

By specifying `np.all(some_array, axis=-1)` you are performing the `all` operation over the last axis, which is where the RGB values are. You see that there was, in this test array, only one such pixel (at `A[0,1]`) where that condition was fulfilled.

Comment: This was a nice answer and led me to a solution in 2 lines instead of around 10. Good job!